# Icons not found in tinyMCE laravel 7

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I hope you all doing well. I am working on a laravel project where I need tinyMCE editor. TinyMCE is working perfectly but 'not found' is showing instead of menu icons.

**How i setup tinyMCE**

> 1. npm install -D tinymce (add tinymce dependency in package.json)
>
> **2. resources/js/app.js**
>
> ```
> require('tinymce/themes/silver');
> import tinymce from 'tinymce';
> tinymce.init({     selector: 'textarea#inputCategoryContent', //textarea id    height: 400,    skin: false,    content_css: false,
> })
> ```

**Error**

[image: "What is showing"]

**Console**

[image: Console data]

**What I want**

[image]

> ANY HELP WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED :)

Comment: `/js/icon/defaults/icons.js` is missing on your root (public). Compy and paste it on `public/js/icon/defaults/icons.js`  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.4.2/icons/default/icons.min.js

Comment: @sta Sorry, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If someone still experience this issue:

Following issue on tinymce:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/5687

Since version 5.3.0 icons are loaded differently.

In my case I had to load the icons in webpack.mix.js with

```
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/tinymce/icons/','public/js/icons/');
```

Answer (score -1):

put this script in your blade:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#editor',
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '/upload');
            var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var json;
                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }
                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }
                success(json.location);
            };
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            xhr.send(formData);
        }
    });
</script>
```

dont forget to set your tinymce id and your upload route